# Is it possible to process a file in Django without saving it?

Tags: python, django

I am using `pdftk` for processing a PDF file.

```
new_doc.save()
url = "/docs/" +settings.MEDIA_URL + new_doc.pdf_file.name
command = 'pdftk '+url+" dump_data_fields"
```

The problem is that I have to use `new_doc.save` before `pdftk`.

Is there any way to get `pdftk` to process the file without saving it?

Comment: `pdftk` takes input on stdin if the filename is `-`, so it is perfectly possible, provided `new_doc` can be streamed. How comfortable are you with using `subprocess` pipes?

Comment: I am ready to learn new things so just give idea what you want to say. i will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with [`subprocess.PIPE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) as the `stdin` and `stdout` arguments. Because `pdftk` can take input from `stdin` you can then 'write' your file straight to `pdftk` instead of to the filesystem:

```
import subprocess

command = ['pdftk', '-', 'dump_data_fields']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errorout = p.communicate(input=new_doc_data)
```

The [`Popen.communicate()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns both the `stdout` and `stderr` results.

Note that the `input` argument to `.communicate()` needs to be a string. If `new_doc` is some kind of file object, you'll have to pass in the result of `new_doc.read()` or similar; in the example above I used the variable name `new_doc_data` to indicate that you pass in the data from `new_doc` as a string as I don't know what API you can use on those objects.

Comment: I am uploading the file using the django form and before saving the file with myobject.save , i want to perform some validation on fields. and if thats valid then i want to save into my desired location. I didn't get how to get that `new_doc_data` because when django form is submitted i don't know where will be that file location before saved

Comment: @user32: Uploaded files have a `.read()` method, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.read

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is with StringIO

I'm assuming that at some point new_doc is from a template and it is text of some kind. in this case you can do something like this.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
new_doc = 'foobar'
doc = StringIO(new_doc)
doc.seek(0)
doc.read()
```

output will be 'foobar'

The first line import StringIO (for a faster version do From cStringIO import StringIO). we then create a string and instantiate a StringIO object with it. From there its pretty much like a

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the OP at all. *How* is this going to be sent to `pdftk` (an external command)?

Comment: I agree, Now that I know the little nugget of information that pdftk is an external command. Possibly the question needs to be updated to specify this?

Comment: It was clear enough, I thought. The question *is* a little sparse on detail, but the `command` variable was a hint, and I looked up the `pdftk` command to see if it took stdin data instead of an input file earlier (see my comment below the question).

Comment: @Martjin Pieters. It could be send via HttpResponse! Read the documentation. I do this in my django project and it works!